# Filling / re-expanding missing values in sequence, not imputation

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- expand.grid(
    id = 1:3, 
    key = 1:10) %>%
    filter(!(id == 1 & key <= 4)) %>%
    filter(!(id == 2 & key %in% c(1:3, 6, 7, 10))) %>%
    filter(!(id == 3 & key %in% c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7:10))) %>%
    arrange(id, key) %>%
    cbind(value = c(10, 11, 15, 17, 20, 30, 1, 6, 8, 100, 0.2, 0.7))
```

- `id == 1` goes to `key == 10`
- `id == 2` goes to `key == 9`
- `id == 3` goes to `key == 6`

I want to fill / re-expand the integer sequence for `key` up to maximum value of key, the values can be NA (this is not an imputation problem)...

So for `id == 3` I want to have keys 1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, **6**... with values == `NA`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a job for tidyr's `complete`.  You want to expand to the max value of `key` within each id or overall in the dataset?  And `key` should start at 1?

Comment: Fwiw, you do not need to edit tags to match answers. It's fine to leave it tagged with whatever you had in mind when you asked.

Comment: @Frank thanks for the heads up! Just trying to make the question more accessible for future searches/searchers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add one more piece to your pipe ironically named `complete`:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- expand.grid(
  id = 1:3, 
  key = 1:10) %>%
  filter(!(id == 1 & key <= 4)) %>%
  filter(!(id == 2 & key %in% c(1:3, 6, 7, 10))) %>%
  filter(!(id == 3 & key %in% c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7:10))) %>%
  arrange(id, key) %>%
  cbind(value = c(10, 11, 15, 17, 20, 30, 1, 6, 8, 100, 0.2, 0.7)) %>%
  complete(id, key)
#    id key value
# 1   1   3    NA
# 2   1   4    NA
# 3   1   5  10.0
# 4   1   6  11.0
# 5   1   7  15.0
# 6   1   8  17.0
# 7   1   9  20.0
# 8   1  10  30.0
# 9   2   3    NA
# 10  2   4   1.0
```

**Edit**

To go beyond the keys in the data use:

```
complete(df, id, key = 1:10)
```

Comment: Awesome. What happens if my key doesn't start at 1? I hacked a solution: ` %>% rbind(c(id = 1, key = 1, value = NA))` and then used complete(). Looks like complete() has a fill argument, but I can't get it working?

Comment: Yes if you want to expand beyond the `key`, define the sequence.

Comment: Good approach with complete.  Plus one.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a sequence starting at 1 and going up to the maximum value of `key` for each `id`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% complete(key = seq(max(key)))
## Source: local data frame [25 x 3]
## Groups: id [3]
## 
##       id   key value
##    <int> <int> <dbl>
## 1      1     1    NA
## 2      1     2    NA
## 3      1     3    NA
## 4      1     4    NA
## 5      1     5    10
## 6      1     6    11
## 7      1     7    15
## 8      1     8    17
## 9      1     9    20
## 10     1    10    30
## # ... with 15 more rows
```